# how to add a choice field to django user model

Tags: django, django-users

I am completely satisfied with the way user model handles the auth, but I want to add a choice field to it that the users could choose between being a patient, doctor or a regular user. then creating the profile model according to their chosen field. for instance the patients have info about their sickness but doctors don't. is there any other way except abstractuser ? because I really don't want to start make another project again from scratch.should I do something with my profile model? I just want to know who the user is. thank you for the responses

this is my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

and this is my forms.py:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']


class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

Comment: Try to make a **`CharField`** or **`IntegerField`** with [**`choice`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) option in **`Profile`** model may help you.

Comment: it wont work because I want to know if the user is patient or a doctor before making their profile